# NextJs AWS s3 CORS issue even with headers and config set

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, axios, cors

I'm getting the following CORS issue when trying to upload to my s3 bucket even though I have both the configurations on my bucket set to allow cross origin requests as well as the headers in axios request:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here's my request:

```
const upload = await axios.put(url, file, {
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT",
    "Content-Type": fileType,
  },
});
```

And my config for my bucket:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Any idea why I'm still getting a CORS issue?